# Querying and modifying an existing database with @Entity class codes and with entityManager

Tags: spring, jpa

I have a problem on telling what i need.

I am using JPA and Spring.

I have `@Entity` codes,

I have a database that is built on above `@Entity class MyEntity` codes.

In my application i need to `save(myEntity)` `update` `delete` with `entityManager`.

Is this possible and how?

SO far i feel like JPA and Spring manage databases only they create from @Entity codes, is the opposite thing possible? Without creating database tables can i use entityManager with @Entity class codes to update and query the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, of course it's possible. What would be the point of an ORM that you can't use for saving, deleting and updating entities? EntityManager has the persist(), merge() and remove() methods.
2. The way the tables are created is irrelevant. Tables are tables and columns are columns. If the fields, associations and mappings match with the tables and columns in the database, everything will run fine.

This is extremely basic stuff that you need to understand before even considering using JPA. Read a book or tutorial about JPA, because not understanding how it works won't lead you anywhere, and StackOverflow answers can't teach you that.

Comment: Thanks very much, i am going to read a book, you are right about searching answer only here. Before ask here I tried sth and could not achieve, thus i thought JPA do not know the tables names like `MY_ENITY` for example for a class `@Entity class MyEntity`. And i thourght the JPA must create the tables in a project to know the names of tables, thus gives names on its own, thus can relate to tables.

Comment: Can you give a clue on how can i introduce tables to my project JPA, or do i need it?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "introduce tables to a project".

Comment: I mean should i do something to make JPA know about table names related to `@Entities`

Comment: That's also basic stuff. Annotate the entity with the Table annotation.